# Are all fibres of a trivial fibre space over X with fibre F canonically homeomorphic with F?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, fiber-bundles

In the category of topological spaces,
a fibre space (E, X, p) is a triple of a morphism (continuous map) p of E to X.

If j is a monomrphism of x to X where x is a final object, the fibre of x is a pull back of j and p.

If E is the product of X and F (its topology may not be the product topology) and p is the projection of E on X (need to be continuous), then call it a trivial fibre space over X with fibre F.

Now, my question is whether the fibre of x isomorphic (homeomorphic) to F.

I know it is true for E with the product topology, however,in 1.4 of Grothendieck's "A general theory of fibre spaces with structure sheaf", discussing more generally but without explanations.

Comment: by definition all $p^{-1}(x)$ got to be homeomorphic to the fiber space

Comment: I can't understand, could you explain the detail? the topology of the fibre of x is induced by E...

Comment: for the product $X\times F$ with projection $p:X\times F\to X$ given by $p(x,f)=x$ you got $p^{-1}(x)=x\times F$, right?

Comment: yes, but why is it homeomorphic to F?

Comment: Ad hoc, when  we're talking in a topological scene

Comment: besides, there in Grothendieck's notes, he said: *All the fibres are canonically homeomorphic to $F$*

Comment: that's where  i can't understand, how to show that? without assuming product top.

Comment: Without assuming some coherence among the topology $\tau$ on $F$ and the one, say $\sigma$, on the product $X\times F$, it's really easy to build counter-examples. For instance, suppose $F$ has at least two elements and take $X = \{\emptyset\}$ (the singleton with its unique topology) and put on $X\times F \cong F$ a topology $\sigma$ different from $\tau$ (the initial and terminal topology, for example). The fiber is then homeomorphic to $(F, \sigma)$ and thus not homeomorphic to $(F, \tau)$